# How do you apply a ID to a layer

Tags: css, svg

I've purchased an AI file of UK postcodes; pictured are the layers it uses with each area named "Path"

I want these to be assigned an ID when I export as an SVG, so that I can apply database-driven data to the map.

I understand that it uses the layer name to apply ID, but even when I change the name from  to a layer name, it doesn't apply an ID.  It does add an ID to the parent layers.

I understand that it is likely something in the original AI file I have downloaded, but not sure how to change.

[image]

Edit with example pictures - so as an example, I delete all layers other than one postcode area - name that "show_id", export as SVG with Layer Names selected but it doesn't work. Added to pictures below

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to ask your question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator) instead

Comment: Maybe don't nest it two layers deep. 

Make a single layer with `show_id` as a direct child of the layer. That worked in a test I did.

Comment: https://imgur.com/6B6Dx2H

Comment: I don't think that will resolve my issue - I can create two layers myself, and it applies an ID just fine - it seems to be something in the layout of the original AI document layout I need to resolve?